# How to Serialize and deserialize a lucene ByteBuffersDirectory

Tags: java, lucene

I have some Lucene indexes that are short lived in memory so I'm making use of on heap `ByteBuffersDirectory` however, I would like to be able to serialize the entire directory to a `byte[]` and deserialise back to a `ByteBuffersDirectory` on the other side without touching disk.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

So far I've written a method to create a zipped stream:

```java
    private static ByteArrayOutputStream toZip(ByteBuffersDirectory d) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
            for (String s : d.listAll()) {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(s);
                IndexInput indexInput = d.openInput(s, IOContext.READONCE);
                entry.setSize(indexInput.length());
                zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                for (long i = 0; i < indexInput.length(); i++) {
                    zos.write(indexInput.readByte());
                }
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
            return baos;
        }
    }
```

although I've not been able to then deserialise this back.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something simple since `ByteBuffersDirectory` has some constants for `OUTPUT_AS_ONE_BUFFER` and `OUTPUT_AS_BYTE_ARRAY` but I can't see how their used or find examples.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this:

```java
    public static void serializeDirectory(Directory directory, OutputStream outputStream, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
        try (var os = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream)){
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            for (var file : directory.listAll()) {

                var entry = new ZipEntry(file);
                try (var input = directory.openInput(file, IOContext.READONCE)) {
                    os.putNextEntry(entry);

                    for (var position = 0; position < input.length(); position += buffer.length) {
                        var len = (int) Math.min(input.length() - position, buffer.length);

                        input.readBytes(buffer, 0, len);
                        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }

                }
                os.closeEntry();

            }
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Directory> T deserializeDirectory(Supplier<T> directoryFactory, InputStream inputStream, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
        var directory = directoryFactory.get();
        try (var zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)) {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                try (var output = directory.createOutput(entry.getName(), IOContext.READONCE)) {
                    int read;

                    while ((read = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
                        var dataInput = new ByteArrayDataInput(buffer);
                        output.copyBytes(dataInput, read);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        return directory;
    }
```

example usage:

```java
var bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
serializeDirectory(originalByteBufferDirectory, bos, 1024);
var result = deserializeDirectory(ByteBuffersDirectory::new, new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()), 1024);
```